# Json data extracting in android

Tags: android, json

i want to extract the given json arry in android,

```
          [{"Outofserviceday":{"outofservice":"2013-02-22"}},   
             {"Outofserviceday":{"outofservice":"2013-02-27"}},  
               {"Outofserviceday":{"outofservice":"2013-02-28"}}]
```

i have the code for extracting the json data like given below

```
            [{"Requestcard":{"id":"994","userprofile_id":"14","userprofile_name":"Syed 
               Imran","company_name":"DLF Akruti Park, Hinjewadi, Pune,  
                     Maharashtra","sex":"male","travel_date":"2013-02-12"}}]
```

in this case we can retrive the json boject using the code

```
               JSONObject menuObject = json_data.getJSONObject("Requestcard");
```

and retrieve each element by

```
                  requestid= menuObject.getString("id");
```

**But in the first case how we identify each Outofserviceday in the json array ? and How extract each data ???**

Comment: Have you solved your problem?

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like below, can create jsonArray from string json data and then can extracts json objects in a loop or so.

```
     String json =" [{\"Outofserviceday\":{\"outofservice\":\"2013-02-22\"}}]"; //json-data which is basically a json array

        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(json); / creating an jsonarray

        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) { 
            // you can have jsonObject from json array here in the loop
        }
```

Comment: Hi Tamilarasi Sivaraj , i already have this code,every jsondata name is outofserviceday,how to seperately extract these data , thats my question

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
JSONArray json1= json.getJSONArray("data");
 if (json1.length()!=0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < json1.length(); i++) {

                    String name = json1.getJSONObject(i).getString("name");

 }
 }
```

Comment: have you print the JSONObject in your logcat?

Answer (score 1):

With the help of below code you can retrieve the value of outofservice

```
JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(your data);
for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
JSONObject jOutOfServiceDay = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
JSONObject jobj = jOutOfServiceDay.getJSONObject("Outofserviceday");
Log.i("Required data is:", "" + jobj.getString("outofservice"));
}
```

Comment: Hi Harish i got your answer, and also i tried that one, but my problem is there are three json object "Outofservideday" and when we use the code JSONObject jobj = jOutOfServiceDay.getJSONObject("Outofserviceday"); thre is a confusion   for getting whic json object because all the names are same

Comment: If You don't want to display all 3,Then if you want to know which one is displaying, for that you need to get the length of the array then you need to get those according to index number.